# Race condition with React hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm putting the finishing touches on my first React application. But one annoying problem: I need to cache thumbnails for the items I am displaying. So I'm using a useEffect which can be simply stated like this:

```
  var thumbnailLookUp = {};

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("http://localhost:3003/thumbnailPreload")
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        for (var row of data) {
          thumbnailLookUp[row.uuid] = row.thumb;
        }
      })
      .then(countClips())
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err.message);
      })
  }, []);
```

The countClips function assembles the data list which will be rendered by a map() in the primary render. This includes the following, where CardMedia is a @mui custom component:

```
              <CardMedia
                component="img"
                height="100"
                src={`https://d3pe68qfxlhu0a.cloudfront.net/${
                  thumbnailLookUp[event.uuid]
                }`}
              />
```

Well here's the thing. When I do a full reload of the page, half the time this works, and the other half the time I get undefined for the results of every thumbnailLookUp[event.uuid]. It's consistent: if one fails, they all fail, if one succeeds, they all succeed. This tells me there's some kind of a race condition between the effect and the render, which is not something I've ever read about. I can guarantee success by placing a breakpoint!

How can I tighten this up so that thumbnailLookUp is always populated before the render (or a second render, if that's really necessary)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make sure that that `thumbnailLookUp` is always populated before the render you should wait for the value to exist before actually rendering the `CardMedia` component.

You can do this by checking that by writing this:

```
{thumbnailLookUp && (
  <CardMedia
    component="img"
    height="100"
    src={`https://d3pe68qfxlhu0a.cloudfront.net/${
      thumbnailLookUp[event.uuid]
    }`}
  />
)}
```

But given your current implementation, you also need to keep that `thumbnailLookUp` in the component lifecycle state, and it should initializes as undefined so that nothing gets rendered immediately (since `{}` is truthy).

In the end you should have this:

```
function MyComponent() {
  const [thumbnailLookUp, setThumbnailLookup] = useState(); // this initializes as undefined

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(...)
      ...
      .then((data) => {
        const newLookup = {};
        for (var row of data) {
          newLookup[row.uuid] = row.thumb;
        }
        setThumbnailLookup(newLookup);
      })
      ...

  }, [])

  return ...;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Barry, for the core insight, namely that thumbnailLookup needs to be part of state. Now we have a situation in which the screen initially has to render twice. The first time, everything is basically set up, but there's no content. Then the thumbnails load, and a moment later it re-renders with content. This is just a little bit awkward; I wonder if there's a better way.

Comment: Are you saying you'd like some sort of fallback in there?

Comment: Barry, what do you mean by fallback?

Comment: Well, in the longer term this strategy did not work well. I gradually realized that after making this change, my App function started being called several times on startup, and twice on changes of tab in a <Tabs> group. Something about this state dependency can make things go crazy, so it seems!

Comment: By fallback I mean render another image (that doesn't need to load) in place so that the UX feels more smooth.. Regarding your other issues, I think you need to spend more time dabbling and learning how react lifecycle methods work across components. You're question didn't contain enough context to tackle these follow up issues that you're dealing with.